Speeding up a VBA function
I have the following VBA function which is called multiple times in a spreadsheet. Is there a way I can make it more efficient?
Function Fx(x As Double, c As Double)
Dim b As Double
Dim g As Double

Dim alpha As Double
Dim beta As Double
Dim gamma As Double
Dim delta As Double

alpha = 3.1
beta = -0.15
gamma = 0.78
delta = 0.12

'derive implied b and g
b = Exp(alpha + beta * c * (1 + c))
g = Exp((gamma + delta * c) * c)

Fx = (Log(((g - 1) * b + (1 - b * g) * b ^ x) / (1 - b))) / Log(b * g)

out:

End Function


alpha beta gamma and delta should probably be constants declared outside the function, but I can't see any other real inefficiencies in the code.

Probably alpha, beta, gamma and delta could be declared as Single instead of Double  (Check Excel VBA Single VS Double Data Type whch takes less memory (Single is 4 bytes and Double 8 bytes) but not a real inefficiency

@FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Then they need to be converted to Double at runtime, so potential even contra productive.

You say that your function is called multiple times, and indeed, increasing your function's performance might indeed increase general performance. However, the problem with the performance can also be in the calling of that function: I can imagine you're using some macro, calling that function. Do you disable events at the start of your macro (and enable them again afterwards)? In other words, can you show us how you call that function?

@Dominique it's used in Excel itself by calling the function - don't use it in VBA at all

@user33484: you might have a point: I just executed this function about 30,000 times and it took about five seconds.

What do you mean by "make it more efficient"? Please explain how you are defining efficiency, and list the current performance by that metric and what an acceptable performance by that metric would be, so that this can be answered directly and objectively.

I don't think you can speed up the function itself significantly. I made a test with an Excel sheet, containing 50.000 rows of data. When I use the function as a formula =fx(A2, B2), it takes 8 to 10 seconds to calculate the data.
However, if I use VBA, read the 50.000 rows into memory (into arrays), loop over all data, calculate the results into another array and write back that array at the end (all 50.000 rows at once), it runs instantly.
So likely the time that is needed is mainly used by the round trips between Excel and VBA.
Testfunction used:
Sub test()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        Dim x: x = .Range("A2:A50000")
        Dim c: c = .Range("B2:B50000")
        ReDim res(LBound(x) To UBound(x), 1 To 1)
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To UBound(x)
            res(i, 1) = Fx(CDbl(x(i, 1)), CDbl(c(i, 1)))
        Next
        .Range("D2:D50000") = res
    End With
End Sub

However, instead of VBA, you can also use a native Excel formula like this (works only for Office 365 or Office 2021 or newer). It assumes that your input data lives in columns A and B and that you have named ranges for the values of alpha, beta, gamma and delta. This takes less than a second for my 50.000 test rows.
= LET(b,EXP(alpha + beta * B2 * (1 + B2)),g,EXP((gamma + delta * B2) * B2),(LOG(((g - 1) * b + (1 - b * g) * b ^ A2) / (1 - b))) / LOG(b * g))


As an aside, does the LET function work faster if you supply the two columns as arrays rather than scalars? I wonder if there is an overhead in Excel parsing the formula, which is mitigated by using arrays?

No idea. But with such short execution times, I wouldn't really bother.

If this is a UDF, defined to be called from a spreadsheet cell, one suggestion would be to try moving the function to a spreadsheet LAMBDA, as it is a simple (and pure) function, without loops, additional libraries/references or external data access etc:
=LAMBDA(x,c,
        LET(alpha,3.1,
            beta,-0.15,
            gamma,0.78,
            delta,0.12,
            b,EXP(alpha + beta * c * (1+c)),
            g,EXP((gamma*delta*c)*c),
            (LN(((g-1)*b+(1-b*g) *b ^ x)/(1-b)))/LN(b*g)
            )
        )

And define this as the Name Fx in the Name Manager.
A refinement might be to store alpha,beta etc in Name'd cells in the sheet and refer to those names, rather than hard-code in the function body.
The marshalling of parameters from the spreadsheet to the VBA function is not cost-less in terms of execution time, so this might speed things up.
A side-effect benefit is that if you are only using VBA for these functions, your sheet becomes an .xlsx rather than .xlsm.
EDIT: For @MGonet's great spot on LOG vs LN

Remember that LOG function in Excel is not the same as Log in VBA. In Excel you should use LN function as an equivalent of Log in VBA.

The calculation of this function can only be minimally optimized. If there is any inefficiency in the calculations, it is probably in a different place.
Function Fxa(x As Double, _
             c As Double)

Dim b As Double
Dim bg As Double
Dim lbg As Double

Dim alpha As Double
Dim beta As Double
Dim gamma As Double
Dim delta As Double

alpha = 3.1
beta = -0.15
gamma = 0.63   ' 0.78
delta = -0.03  ' 0.12

'derive implied b and g

b = alpha + beta * c * (1 + c)
lbg = alpha + gamma * c + delta * c ^ 2
b = Exp(b)
bg = Exp(lbg)
Fxa = Log((bg - b + (1 - bg) * b ^ x) / (1 - b)) / lbg

out:
End Function

